# Cant install gonoware/laravel-maps

Tags: laravel, composer-php, maps

I have troubles installing gonoware/laravel-maps on Laravel version 8.

When I do "composer require gonoware/laravel-maps" in my commander I get some errors:

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - gonoware/laravel-maps v1.3.0 requires illuminate/support ^5.5|^6.0|^7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
    - gonoware/laravel-maps v1.3.1 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires gonoware/laravel-maps ^1.3 -> satisfiable by gonoware/laravel-maps[v1.3.0, v1.3.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

`gonoware/laravel-maps` is not compatible with Laravel 8, as written in the error message. There's already an [open bug report](https://gitlab.com/gonoware/laravel-maps/-/issues/20) about this. Until this is fixed, you have no possibility to install the package while also using Laravel 8.